# python, create multiple matplotlib button widgets in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, tkinter, button

I need to generate a variable number (total) of button widgets in matplotlib and have each one store a different number in the variable, var.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button as BT

total = 4

class Index:
    ind = 0
        
    def plot_pick(self, event):
        var=event
        print(var)

ax_chooseplot={}
chooseplot_BT={}
callback=Index()

for i in range(0,total):
    loc=0.95-i*0.03
    ax_chooseplot[i] = plt.axes([loc-0.002, 0.87, 0.02, 0.03])
    chooseplot_BT[i] = BT(ax_chooseplot[i], '')
    chooseplot_BT[i].on_clicked(callback.plot_pick(i))         
    
plt.show()
```

This code prints i sequentially then on pressing any button:

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

It seems like the function "plot_pick" is being called during the for loop and then the value of i is being discarded?

I've seen this issue addressed for tkinter buttons but I've been unable to apply those answers to matplotlib embedded buttons. Is there an easy way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from the way you are passing the `i` argument to your `plot_pick` function. Passing it directly to your function won't work. A possible alternative is to use `functools.partial`. You can find below an example where I use  `functools.partial` to print the index of the button that was clicked on:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button as BT
import functools

total = 4

class Index:
    ind = 0

    def plot_pick(self,i, event):
        print('Button '+str(i))
        

ax_chooseplot={}
chooseplot_BT={}
callback=Index()


for i in range(0,total):
    loc=0.95-i*0.03
    ax_chooseplot[i] = plt.axes([loc-0.002, 0.87, 0.02, 0.03])
    chooseplot_BT[i] = BT(ax_chooseplot[i], str(i))
    chooseplot_BT[i].on_clicked(functools.partial(callback.plot_pick,i))  
   
    
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked!

Comment: You are welcome. If you are happy with the results, you can mark the question as answered by ticking the green checkmark next to my answer. Thx!